# Blogger: how to link comments to my non-blogger website?

Tags: wordpress, openid, google-plus, blogger, hosted

I host my own WordPress website on my own domain, but most of my peers have Blogger sites.

When they comment on each others sites, their comments appear *alongside* their **name**, **avatar**, and **link back to their blog**, (because they are also Blogger users). But when I try to post a comment, (with any of the allowed Authentication methods), I get an "unknown" avatar, and cannot get my non-Blogger URL to appear.

The allowed Authentication methods are:

- Google Account
- LiveJournal
- WordPress
- TypePad
- AIM
- OpenID

I can setup an account with any of these services, but when I post a comment it links it back to my profile on each of these services, not to my own domain / website. I have also tried setting up OpenID delegation using my website to Google+, but this only allows me to sign in using my domain, it still posts linking my Google+ profile rather than my site.

I have spent the best part of a day researching this, and I can't find an answer.

**How do I comment on Blogger hosted sites, using my non-Blogger domain and avatar as my ID?**